# Using a metaclass on a class drived from another class implemented in C

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, metaclass

I am working on a `ctypes` drop-in-replacement / extension and ran into an issue I do not fully understand.

I am trying to build a class factory for call-back function decorators similar to [CFUNCTYPE](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3d07c1ee1d2d475b74816117981d6ec752c26c23/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py#L73) and [WINFUNCTYPE](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3d07c1ee1d2d475b74816117981d6ec752c26c23/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py#L111). Both factories produce classes derived from `ctypes._CFuncPtr`. Like every `ctypes` function interface, they have properties like `argtypes` and `restype`. I want to extend the classes allowing an additional property named `some_param` and I thought, why not, let's try this with "getter" and "setter" methods - how hard can it be ...

Because I am trying to use "getter" and "setter" methods (`@property`) on a property of a *class* (NOT a property of objects), I ended up writing a metaclass. Because my class is derived from `ctypes._CFuncPtr`, I *think* my metaclass must be derived from `ctypes._CFuncPtr.__class__` (I could be wrong here).

The example below *works*, sort of:

```py
import ctypes

class a_class:

    def b_function(self, some_param_parg):

        class c_class_meta(ctypes._CFuncPtr.__class__):
            def __init__(cls, *args):
                super().__init__(*args) # no idea if this is good ...
                cls._some_param_ = some_param_parg
            @property
            def some_param(cls):
                return cls._some_param_
            @some_param.setter
            def some_param(cls, value):
                if not isinstance(value, list):
                    raise TypeError('some_param must be a list')
                cls._some_param_ = value

        class c_class(ctypes._CFuncPtr, metaclass = c_class_meta):
            _argtypes_ = ()
            _restype_ = None
            _flags_ = ctypes._FUNCFLAG_STDCALL # change for CFUNCTYPE or WINFUNCTYPE etc ...

        return c_class

d_class = a_class().b_function([1, 2, 3])
print(d_class.some_param)
d_class.some_param = [2, 6]
print(d_class.some_param)
d_class.some_param = {} # Raises an error - as expected
```

So far so good - using the above any further does NOT work anymore. The following *pseudo-code* (if used on an actual function from a DLL or shared object) will fail - in fact, it will cause the CPython interpreter to segfault ...

```py
some_routine = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary('some.dll').some_routine
func_type = d_class(ctypes.c_int16, ctypes.c_int16) # similar to CFUNCTYPE/WINFUNCTYPE
func_type.some_param = [4, 5, 6] # my "special" property
some_routine.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int16, func_type)
@func_type
def demo(x):
    return x - 1
some_routine(4, demo) # segfaults HERE!
```

I am not entirely sure what goes wrong. `ctypes._CFuncPtr` is implemented in C, which could be a relevant limitation ... I could also have made a mistake in the implementation of the metaclass. Can someone enlighten me?

(For additional context, I am working on [this function](https://github.com/pleiszenburg/zugbruecke/blob/4467f2a0d225134d195cc1c75c6d2310bee5e3ca/src/zugbruecke/core/data/arg_definition.py#L56).)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe ctypes metaclasses simply won't work nicely being subclasses - since it is itself written in C, it may bypass the routes inheritance imposes for some shortcuts and end up in failures.

Ideally this "bad behavior" would have to be properly documented, filled as bugs against CPython's ctypes and fixed - to my knowledge there are not many people who can fix ctypes bugs.

On the other hand, having a metaclass just because you want a property-like attribute at class level is overkill.

Python's `property` itself is just pre-made, very useful builtin class that implements the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access). Any class you create yourself that implements proper `__get__` and `__set__` methods can replace "property" (and often, when logic is shared across property-attributes, leads to shorter, non duplicated code)

On a second though, unfortunately, descriptor setters will only work for instances, not for classes (which makes sense, since doing `cls.attr` will already get you the special code-guarded value, and there is no way a `__set__` method could be called on it)

So, if you could work with "manually" setting the values in the `cls.__dict__` and putting your logic in the `__get__` attribute, you could do:

```
PREFIX = "_cls_prop_"

class ClsProperty:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        value = owner.__dict__.get(PREFIX + self.name)
        # Logic to transform/check value goes here:
        if not isinstance(value, list):
            raise TypeError('some_param must be a list')
        return value


def b_function(some_param_arg):

    class c_class(ctypes._CFuncPtr):
        _argtypes_ = ()
        _restype_ = None
        _flags_ = 0 # ctypes._FUNCFLAG_STDCALL # change for CFUNCTYPE or WINFUNCTYPE etc ...

        _some_param_ = ClsProperty()

    setattr(c_class, PREFIX + "_some_param_", some_param_arg) 

    return c_class


d_class = b_function([1, 2, 3])
print(d_class._some_param_)
d_class._some_param_ = [1, 2]
print(d_class._some_param_)
```

If that does not work, I don't think other approaches trying to extend CTypes metaclass will work anyway, but if you want a try, instead of a "meta-property", you might try to customize the metaclass' `__setitem__` instead, to do your parameter checking, instead of using `property`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I thought I would not get one at all. Actually, it was an [answer of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34984506/1672565) to a question of mine that inspired the whole mad project, so thanks for that too ;) I (mildly) edited the code in your answer to reflect how it *should* look like AFAIK (?), but it still does not work. The line `c_class.__dict__[PREFIX + '_some_param_'] = some_param_arg` fails with `TypeError: 'mappingproxy' object does not support item assignment`. I have not yet managed to make some sense of it. What do I have to do to complete the example?

Comment: Yes - sorry for that -  `setattr(c_class, PREFIX + "_some_param_", some_param_arg)` should work there.